# Displaying transparent image in a WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, bitmap, transparent, datagridcolumn

I have been tasked with taking an existing list of transparent .png images (currently housed within an ImageList) and displaying them in a WPF DataGrid based on the ImageID column.

I have set up the DataGridColumn as follows:

```
    _dataTemplateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
    _dataTemplateColumn.Header = "";
    FrameworkElementFactory _factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
    Binding _binding = new Binding("Image");
    _binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    _factory.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, _binding);
    DataTemplate _cellTemplate = new DataTemplate();
    _cellTemplate.VisualTree = _factory;
    _dataTemplateColumn.CellTemplate = _cellTemplate;

    Style _style = new Style();
    _style.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Transparent));
    _dataTemplateColumn.CellStyle = _style;
```

I then create a Custom Object at runtime which includes the image for me and run the following 2 methods on the Image, the first to resize it and the second to convert it into a Bitmap rather than a BitmapImage (which is the only format I have managed to get it working in WPF with so far):

```
    public static Bitmap ResizeImage(this Bitmap Bitmap, Size size)
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap _bitmap = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
            using (Graphics _graphic = Graphics.FromImage((Image)_bitmap))
            {
                _graphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                _graphic.DrawImage(Bitmap, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
            }
            _bitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.Magenta);

            return _bitmap;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this BitmapImage BitmapImage)
    {
        using (MemoryStream _stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BitmapEncoder _encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            _encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(BitmapImage));
            _encoder.Save(_stream);
            System.Drawing.Bitmap _bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(_stream);
            _bitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.Magenta);
            return new Bitmap(_bitmap);
        }
    }
```

The Image is being displayed in the correct size and position in the DataGrid but the transparency is not preserved from the .png format. If anyone knows a better method for me (perhaps it is more correct to take the Image into a resource file first for example?) or a way to get the transparency working within my current code it would be most appreciated!

Comment: Drop all the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` related stuff. It is not needed in WPF. Simply bind the `Image.Source` property to the `Uri` that references the original image file. Resizing is already done by the `Image` control.

Comment: I'm not using an Image control though, the Image needs to be displayed within the DataGridColumn and is done by using the DataGridTemplateColumn?

Comment: Then what is this: `FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));`? `Image` is the [Image control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.Image.aspx).

Comment: Also note the Remarks on [FrameworkElementFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx): `This class is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates, which are subclasses of FrameworkTemplate such as ControlTemplate or DataTemplate; not all of the template functionality is available when you create a template using this class. The recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class.`

Comment: Ah ok, yes you are correct. I'm not sure how to set the Image.SourceProperty to the Uri in the context of my code though? At the point that I set the binding I don't know the Uri as it will only be known later when the data is actually bound?

Comment: I'm doing it programmatically because the DataGrid is served in multiple ways as a Generic paged control. I struggled for a while to get the Image to load at all and this was the only way it worked thus far!

Comment: You could still load `DataTemplate` and `Style` resources to set the `CellTemplate` and `CellStyle` properties. No need for FrameworkElementFactory.

Comment: For your binding. You seem to already have a property named `Image`. The type of this property could be `string` or `Uri` (to hold the image file path) or `ImageSource` or a derived type. The rest will work automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example gives you an idea of how it may look like:

XAML:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageCellTemplate">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="100"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var col = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        col.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["ImageCellTemplate"];

        dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);

        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures", "*.jpg"))
        {
            dataGrid.Items.Add(new DataItem { Image = file });
        }
    }
}

public class DataItem
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```